# How do I remove a preview from a post in slack when editing?

Tags: slack

Note: **I AM NOT ASKING HOW TO HIDE A PREVIEW** for myself. I'm asking how to **delete** for **everyone** a preview that has already been posted.

Here is the workflow that I'm talking about

1. Make a post in slack with a youtube link and Click Send

[image]

2. Post shows up with preview

[image]

3. Pick "Edit Message"

[image]

4. Remove the link and pick "Save Changes"

[image]

5. Even though there is no longer a link in the post there is still a preview.

[image]

In fact even changing the link to something else does not fix/remove the preview

Here is pasting a link from imgur

[image]

And here's the result. The link shows imgur, the preview is still Youtube

[image]

How do I remove the preview when editing? Just like my edits show up for everyone else I want the fact that I removed the link to remove the preview for everyone else as well. It's part of my edit

Answer (score 12):

Using your own example from YouTube, when you hover over the image there is a little cross on the left side of the thumbnail. Click there.

[image: How to remove a preview from YouTube links in Slack]

This creates a dialogue, click on `remove`

[image]

Once the preview is removed, Slack shows your message as `edited`, and the preview is removed from the message. And this change is visible to everyone in the channel.

[image]

Comment: Note: The "Also block previews in the future" option is rather new. @gman, consider accepting this answer; it is unlikely you will receive a better one.

Comment: @noughtnaut: I believe that checkbox only appears if you're an owner or admin of the workspace – [workspace owners/admins can hide link previews/embeds from appearing for specific sites](https://slack.com/help/articles/360001502048-Manage-link-previews-for-your-workspace), which applies to everyone in the workspace.